# QTableView not resizing when resizing main window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview

I've got a GUI in PyQt that does the following:
The main window is a grid layout (2 columns and 3 rows). This is the scheme (soory I can't post images yet):
[image: PicOne]

Now, when resizing the Main Window I'd like the [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#details) widgets to be resized. However, it happens otherwise:
[image: PicTwo]
And the tables stay almost fixed in size (but every size-fixing property is set not to fix anything), they just expand for about 50 píxels. I've tried changing the main layout to a horizontal layout and then putting vertical layouts there but no change. I'm designing the GUI with the `QtDesigner` as I have no clue on how to doing it by hand-writing the code, and I need to export it to python.

What's the property determining which layout gets expanded and which one not?

Comment: It's hard for us to see what's wrong if you don't post any source code. Preferably make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can just copy-past-run. Indeed this a bit harder if you use QtDesigner to make your GUI. I prefer coding by hand as this gives more insight and the time spend on coding the layout is usually a small fraction of the total programming time. If you don't know where to start you an download the source distribution of PyQt and look in the examples directory. These are the original Qt examples ported to Python.

Comment: Maybe you should try hand code it and bypass `QtDesigner` so you will learn the basics of [Qt Layout System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! As there were some LineEdits on the left side, they had to expand too. Setting its expanding policy to "fixed" or setting a maximum fixed it.

Thanks everybody for the help and dont worry, i'm going to learn to handwrite Qt GUIs soon.